# Почему внедрение библиотеки не работает?

Tags: c++

Пытался написать код на внедрение библиотеки в только что созданный процесс, но что-то не получается. Функция inject возвращает true, но сама библиотека в процесс не загружается. Пожалуйста, подскажите в чём проблема. Всё x64.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

bool inject(HANDLE processHandle, const wchar_t* dllPath)
{
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll");
    if (module)
    {
        FARPROC address = GetProcAddress(module, "LoadLibraryA");
        if (address)
        {
            LPVOID memory = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, NULL, wcslen(dllPath) + 1, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
            if (memory)
            {
                if (WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, memory, dllPath, wcslen(dllPath) + 1, NULL))
                {
                    if (CreateRemoteThread(processHandle, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)address, memory, NULL, NULL))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* CloseHandle(processHandle);
    VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, memory, 0, MEM_RELEASE); */

    return false;
}

bool fileExists(LPCWSTR name)
{
    return GetFileAttributesW(name) != -1;
}

int main()
{
    const wchar_t APP_NAME[8]  = L"app.exe";
    const wchar_t DLL_64  [12] = L"library.dll";

    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));

    wchar_t path[MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName(DLL_64, MAX_PATH, path, 0);

    if (CreateProcess(APP_NAME, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &startupInfo, &processInfo))
    {
        std::wcout << L"dll path: " << path << std::endl;
        std::wcout << L"inject result: " << inject(processInfo.hProcess, path) << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И ещё, не понимаю почему некоторые пишут wcslen(dllPath) + 1 а некоторые просто wcslen(dllPath). Как правильнее?

Comment: Я так понимаю у меня завёлся личный хейтер который каждый мой вопрос минусует даже не объясняя почему.